# How to display elements side by side in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

      function drawRegionsMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};

        var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Supposedly, I want to display a GeoChart on a webpage, and the codes above are from this link:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

I try to change the function drawRegionMap() part into a multidimensional array, as per below code snippet:

```
var record = [['Germany', 200], ['United States', 300], ['Brazil', 400], ['Canada', 500], ['France', 600], ['RU', 700]];

      function drawRegionsMap() {

            for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Country', 'Population'],
                    [record[x][y], record[i][j]]
                ]);

                x++; j++;
            }

}
```

but, it didn't show the regions of the world map with the population, as inside the 'var record' array, because supposedly it need to display like in the below link:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

May I know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the codes with these:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Country', 'Density'],
                    [record[i][0], record[i][1]],
                ]);
            }
```

but, it only displays the last element in the array, which is ['RU',700]